# Not able to load UI page beyond login page on Ansible AWX

Tags: nginx, ansible, nginx-reverse-proxy, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I have installed AWX using docker-compose after cloning from GitHub.
I am trying to run Ansible awx from behind nginx as a reverse proxy but on the web page, after entering the login credentials, it is redirecting itself to /api/login/ and showing error as 405 not allowed
[see the image for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNvWR.png)

Can you please suggest if I am doing correctly.

```
    location /awx/ {
          proxy_pass "http://backendawx/";
          proxy_set_header   Host $host;
          proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
          proxy_redirect /awx/ //;
          access_log /var/log/nginx/awx/access.log timed_combined;
          error_log /var/log/nginx/awx/error.log error;
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly do the nginx configuration like below.

nginx configuration:

````
upstream backendawx {
      server HOSTNAME:PORTNUMBER;
    }
  location /awx/ {
          proxy_pass "http://backendawx/#/login/";
          proxy_set_header   Host $host;
          proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
          proxy_redirect /awx/ /#/login/;
          access_log /var/log/nginx/awx/access.log timed_combined;
          error_log /var/log/nginx/awx/error.log error;
    }
location /api/ {
          proxy_pass "http://backendawx/api/";
          proxy_set_header   Host $host;
          proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }  ```
````

Comment: nginx
ansible
nginx-reverse-proxy
ansible-awx
ansible-tower